# GIF Exporting Issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I rendered a video as Quicktime MOV file with RGB+Alpha, so I could convert it into transparent GIF in photoshop by Importing video as "Video Frames to layers"

But when I Exporting it GIF, Photoshop Just Freezes, and Crashed or Giving me this error [[image: Error]]

Is there any way to convert as transparent GIF in another way?

I referred this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOs12GY0yzs

Comment: **Solved:** it's 1920X1080, by Converting in 512X512 Helped me

Answer (score -1):

Converted into 512 X 512 and also 32-bit Colors helped me

Comment: This answer has no sense since a GIF can contain only a 256 color palete, that is an-8 bit image.

Comment: Yup I know but doing that so helped to resolve the problem, converting more into 8-bit also do the same